# In manifest v3 is conditional redirecting possible?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We have a Chrome extension that we use that allows our developers to quickly setup redirects for certain URLs, for easier debugging across different clients' sites. It currently uses manifest v2 manifest with webRequestBlocking.

In brief, it behaves something like this:

1. Search for a URL pattern like: `https://www.example.com/c1234/path/to/javascript.js`
2. Use the `c1234` part of the matched URL in an HTTP call to a web service that to look-up the value of a variable, which we'll call `shortName` here.
3. Redirect the URL in #1 to a new URL that follows a pattern something like this: `https://localhost/imp-{shortName}/javascript.js`.

With the [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#type-Redirect) in manifest v3, I'm able to set rules that redirect using regular expressions, but I don't see any way to use a part of the matched URL to look-up a variable from an outside source (step #2) above.

Is this not possible with manfiest v3 at all? I'm using the updateSessionRules API as follows:

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules({ 
  addRules: [
  {
    id: 1,
    action: {
      type: 'redirect',
      redirect: {
        regexSubstitution: '\1://localhost/{shortName}/javascript.js'
      }
    },
    condition: {
      regexFilter: '^(https?):.+(example.com).+(c[0-9]+).+javascript.+$'
    }
  }
];
  rules,
  removeRuleIds: [1]
});
```

In manifest v2, I used [chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onBeforeRequest) to intercept *before* the request was made:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    return redirectOnMatch(details);
  },
  {
    urls : ["<all_urls>"]
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

The `redirectOnMatch` function would first check to see if the URL matched a pattern, and if it did, extract the `c1234` value and use it in an HTTP call.

Is there any way to have code run and set the redirect rules before the request is made in manifest v3?

Comment: Only an extension force-installed via policies can use webRequestBlocking in MV3. Not possible for a normal extension with declarativeNetRequest. Report your use case to https://crbug.com so they know they broke it.

Comment: Should I log it as a "defect report from user" or some other issue type?